# Set the number of threads created by JVM when initializing it through JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Is there a way to set a limit for the number of threads created by JVM when starting it through JNI?

I would like to set a maximum limit for the number of threads created if it is possible.

Comment: What JVM thread pool?

Comment: @EJP I edited the question

Comment: Why? How do you know how many threads the JVM needs to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM doesn't have thread pool, the threads are created and managed by the code - the VM could only kill them on exit. Clearly such restricted app will not work if you don't give it all threads that it needs. How would you choose which thread is critical for the application and which is not? It doesn't make sense.

You can set resources that a particular process can use on the OS level, but it is rather for stopping some ill performing process from killing your system.

As @StephenC said there is a way to block the creation of new Threads in a JVM using custom SecurityManager - this could be handy in some scenarios - eg. if you have some application that runs untrusted code from clients - you can restrict the clients to not create new threads.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am coming from a C++ background and that's why the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to set the size of the JVM thread pool ...

A JVM doesn't have a thread pool.

> Is there a way to set a limit for the number of threads created by JVM when starting it through JNI?

No.

If you want to restrict the number of threads created, you could possibly implement this using a custom `SecurityManager`.   For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536809/139985

Or possibly at the OS level using UNIX `ulimit -T` or similar.

But if you can *trust* the Java code that you are running in the "child" JVM, it is better to get it (i.e. the developer) to use a Java SE library (e.g. an `ExecutorService` with a bounded thread-pool) or a third party thread-pool implementation.